# does the azure App Service Authentication module suport azure aad b2c?

Tags: azure, uwp, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-msal

I have a UWP app that needs a backend. I want to use azure app service and need set an authentication for the background. 
The App Service Authentication module can easily set and Authentication for the app.

I wish to use AAD B2C, but the App Service authentication module say that it does not support aad 2.0/msal. So, does the App Service Authentication module can support AAD B2C?

And, how can I verify the AAD B2C token signature on the webservice? Microsoft doc said can use some library to verify the AAD B2C token signature, can msal be used to Verify the AAD B2C token signature on a asp.net core web service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does the App Service Authentication module can support AAD B2C?

Yes, App Service easy auth supports AAD B2C, you can configure it under **Advanced** management mode.

[image]

Set the **Client ID** to be the Application Client ID from **Azure AD B2C tenant**.

Set the **Issue URL** to be the Metadata Endpoint for the policy.

```
https://tonyb2ctest.b2clogin.com/tonyb2ctest.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_testsignupin
```

**Note**: don't forget to set the reply url in azure ad tenant application `https://XXX.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback`

> how can I verify the AAD B2C token signature on the webservice?

Many open-source libraries are available for validating JWTs, it doesn't matter with Azure App service.

Comment: thanks for your help.  azure says that the Authentication module  runs in the same sandbox as your application code.  Does the App Service Authentication module share the computing resource of my app service plan/VM ?   If I use  an UWP client with the Authentication module, does it means that I have to use the app service mobile SDK both in the UWP app and asp.net service webapi, and I will can't use asp.net core?(the azure mobile app sdk only can run for asp.net 4.6). thank you.

Comment: AZURE AD B2C The browser page is mis-rendered in Embedded Webviews with MSAL.net web(new versio userflow (Recommended)).  Where Can I notice azure fix this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64101050/azure-ad-b2c-the-browser-page-is-mis-rendered-in-embedded-webviews-with-msal-net/64136080#64136080