# Authentication with App Service using Azure B2C not working

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to integrate Azure AD B2C with my App Service using the Authentication / Authorization menu in the portal (also called EasyAuth).

This is what I did:

1. Registered the application in Azure B2C
2. Recorded the App ID
3. Defined user flows (just Sign In)
4. Set up identity provider (Azure AD)
5. Tested the user flow, with Redirect URI pointing to jwt.ms, to see the result - works fine
6. Enabled Authentication / Authorization in the App Service in the Portal
7. Configured Azure AD authentication with the App ID from above and the link to the endpoint metadata

But now, when I access the App Service, I'm redirected to a "Logging in..." page which immediately goes to the jwt.ms page, with no JWT data, no login page, and no opportunity to enter my credentials.
Just an empty jwt page.

I couldn't find anything in the docs that can explain this.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58788198/does-the-azure-app-service-authentication-module-suport-azure-aad-b2c?answertab=votes#tab-top) helpful?

Comment: I followed exactly the steps outlined there, but that didn't help. I still get immediately redirected back to the app, and no authentication page is displayed.

Comment: Hi @ml123 are you still looking for help on this.?